# Is there an API to manage (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) Custom Reports in Apigee?

Tags: apigee

The main purpose of this API is to manage changes across all environments (DEV, QA, PROD) without having to manually migrate reports. Then, building shell scripts or more advanced CI tools to apply continuous deployment.

I'm looking into the resources available in Apigee Console To Go, but couldn't find  resources to export reports.

http://apigee.com/docs/apigee-api-platform-console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API is here:

GET reports
curl https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/organizations/{orgName}/reports
curl https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/organizations/{orgName}/reports?expand=true

DELETE reports
curl https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/organizations/{orgName}/reports/(reportId}" -X DELETE

where reportId comes from **name** seen in the above GET

POST reports
curl https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/organizations/{orgName}/reports/" -X POST -d "{reportBodyInJson}"

Comment: Cool. Thanks Randy. To complement your answer. To retrieve report definition in JSON, use 
`curl https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/organizations/{org}/reports/{report-id} and when creating report, use include header: curl --data @report_file.json https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/organizations/{org}/reports/ -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"`